# How do you fire a sequence of commands at the command tool?

Tags: scripting, rsync

*I had a previous question (deleted it) and I still don't understand why it is so hard to understand what I'm trying to ask, but I'll try once again and more clearly.*

So I'm copying over several folders over from server A to server B, but the command for each copy process ('rsync') has to be executed from the command line, once for each folder.

So, to copy folder A to server X, I execute a rsync command and once it's done copying, I execute a new rsync command to copy over folder B to server X.

I've did a little research, that probably helps you answer my needs. But I'm looking for a way to write multiple commands at once, that fires one after another if the previous one is finished with his actions (thus finished copying).

Usually, multiple commands are separated on one line by `;` semicolons or `&&` ampersands.
The difference between is that if the first/previous command fails with semicolons, it still continues. If the command produces an error and you had used ampersands, than it will stop.

Thus, I used semicolons in my process and let my computer going on overnight.. but it only executed the first command, even though I written several on one line separated with semicolons. So It should have executed all of them, one by one... So first: How do I correctly execute multiple commands and B, what is wrong with my command?

```
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-02-233653/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ; 
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-09-152837/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-20-201229/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-02-21-130931/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-03-05-113353/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-03-19-162703/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-05-13-215016/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap ;
sudo rsync -v -v -r -h -t —progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-06-01-231321/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap
```

*I separated them with breaks here for readability purposes. Normally it's one whole line*

This usually goes by with a `;` semicolon character

Comment: I guess your problem is the repeated sudo: When the first command finished, probably your sudo password timed out, and the second command won't be executed before you enter your password again. If that is the problem, the solution is to put the whole command chain in a single subshell executed by sudo, like `sudo sh -c 'rsync ...; rsync ...; ...'` Also note that you could simplify your command a lot by making use of `for`.

Comment: But I need sudo with every command, because of protected folders. If I write sudo only once, at start (like you write), will sudo rights ben maintained with every in the whole chain?

Comment: That's the purpose of the `sh -c`. As far as `sudo` is concerned, there's only one command, `sh`, with the two arguments `-c` and `'rsync ...; rsync ...; ...'`. This `sh` is run as root, and thus will also run all those `rsync` commands as root. Therefore the `rsync` commands will have full root permissions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For repeatability I suggest to put the lines into a small script, but without the keyword `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-02-233653/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap  
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-09-152837/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-01-20-201229/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-02-21-130931/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-03-05-113353/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-03-19-162703/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-05-13-215016/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap 
rsync -v -v -r -h -t --progress /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/2014-06-01-231321/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap
```

To run the series of commands, type:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

This way, `sudo` is not timing out during a long command.
There is no need for a semicolon in a script file. By default, each line may fail and the next is executed (to change this, use `set -o errexit`).

I also noticed something fishy in your commands. for the option `--progress` you didn't use a regular *hyphen*, but some other, similar looking character. This could be another source of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: First of all. I do need sudo, since I'm copying over protected folders (TimeMachineBackups, to be specific) which with regular permissions wouldn't copy. The -progress, which actually should've been --progress, simply displays a percentage vision of how much of each file has been copied (in case of gigabyte big files). The actual problem, indeed, like celtschk writes in his comment, is the time-out of the password input. Thus, that should be avoided, if possible. And The command, whether it fails or not, should be executed, no matter what. So set -o errexit isn't needed. Does this work on Mac?

Comment: My solution avoids this problem. The sudo rights are inherited by the shell and only dropped when the script is finished.

Comment: Thanks big time! I will try and if this indeed fits, then you'll get your answer accepted! :)

Comment: You can also verify this by launching the script and looking at the user which owns the shell or rsync in a tool like `top` or `htop`. It should be `root`, not your username. Also, check out the other answer for improving the rsync command (e.g. `-a`)

Answer (score 8):

Note the usage for rsync is `rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST` which means this can be more simply written as

```
 rsync -r -t -h /src1dir /src2 /src3 /destdir
```

which isn't subject to sudo session timeouts. You didn't ask, but the option `-a` is far more comprehensive than `-r -t`.

Comment: And even more compactly as `rsync -r -t -h /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/{2014-01-02-233653,2014-01-09-152837,2014-01-20-201229,...}/SSDaeffer /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap`. Maybe even a `*` in place of the `{}` group for all I know :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing this. The approach you tried would have worked perfectly if each `sudo` did not require you to enter a password. Since it does, the commands would hang since the 2nd would ask for a password and you weren't there to give it. Therefore, you need a way of running everything with a *single* `sudo` call. Here are a few ways of doing this.

1. Write the commands in a script and run the script with `sudo` as explained in @Sebastian's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154065/22222).
2. Run a single `rsync` giving multiple source folders as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154066/22222) by @msw.
3. Build the commands dynamically. It looks like you want to copy all `SSDaeffer` folders to `/Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap`. This means you could simply write

   ```
   sudo rsync -vah /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/*/SSDaeffer \
                   /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap
   ```

   That will copy all `SSDaeffer` folders that are sub-folders of a directory in 
   `/Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS` to `/Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap`. This assumes that you want *all* the `SSDaeffer` folders there. If you only want some of them, you could list them in a file:

   ```
   $ cat file
   2014-01-02-233653
   2014-01-09-152837
   2014-01-20-201229
   2014-02-21-130931
   ```

   Then read the file to get the names you want:

   ```
   sudo while read dir; do 
    rsync -vah /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/$dir/SSDaeffer \
               /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap;
   done < file
   ```

   If your folder names can contain whitespace or other strange characters, use this instead:

   ```
   while IFS= read -r dir; do 
    rsync -vah /Volumes/My\ Book/Backups.backupdb/MbpScs-van-iSCS/$dir/SSDaeffer \
                   /Volumes/BackupMyBook/ViaMacbookMove/DitIsDeMap;
   done < file
   ```
4. Start a root shell with `sudo -i`. This will let you login as the superuser and then you can run commands to your heart's content:

   ```
   $ sudo -i
   Password:
   # rsync -avh /from/dir1 /to/dir
   # rsync -avh /from/dir2 /to/dir
   # rsync -avh /from/dir3 /to/dir
   ```

Comment: Looks great and tells a lot. I'm at the moment successful with Sebastian's solution. I will try yours, at number 3, too soon. Thanks a lot for taking the effort writing such big solution! :)